# Apache VirtualHost - per user ProxyPass

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, proxypass

I'm trying to configure Apache to redirect users to different paths based on their authentication credentials (using *htpasswd*). I've managed to set up *ProxyPass*, which enables the redirection of the request to a custom path, however all of the users now get redirected to the same path. This happens because of using the same `<Location />` directive for all of the users. When I try with `<Location /user123>`, `<Location /user456>`,.. it works like intended, but I'd like for Apache to forward the `/` location to appropriate paths based on provided credentials. Is this possible?

Comment: Could be possible by using rewriterule instead of ProxyPass, it supports variables.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at apache with mod_rewrite. I believe you could do something like the following. The remote_user variable is available to apache in the config.  I believe you can do something like the following.

```
RewriteCond "%{REMOTE_USER}"  "!^$"
RewriteRule "^/(.*)"  "/$1/%{REMOTE_USER}" [R]
```

The condition says if the remote user exists with a value that is not an empty string then rewrite urls with a remote url. You also could do a redirectmatch as well.

```
RedirectMatch "^/(.*)" "/$1/%{REMOTE_USER}"
```

Here are my references.
This shows the variables available to mod_rewrite
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

This show examples of mod_rewrite in action
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: That's pretty much what I imagined. But the OP want's to proxy, not redirect.

Comment: Really not sure about the proxy.  I would put these rewrite rules on whatever is on the receiving end of the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the question more closely, since you are using the apache instance to authenticate using htpasswd file. I believe you can reference the REMOTE_USER variable.

I believe you can use something like the following in your apache config.

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/%{REMOTE_USER}/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/%{REMOTE_USER}/
```

Comment: And if ProxyPass doesn't support variable expansion ; use the  RewriteRule from your other answer, but with a [`P|proxy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) flag rather than the  R|redirect .

Comment: Cool, I was not aware of the P flag.